# Odoo: How to add custom category name to app module's search panel?

Tags: odoo

For example i have app with

```
category = "custom_category"
```

How can i add this category to my search panel in app module ?

[image]

When I created a category, I thought it would come here automatically, but it didn't.

I found the file, where these categories are defined:
`15.0/odoo/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_module_category_data.xml`

But something is not right here! When I delete a record from here, for example:

```
<!--        <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_human_resources">-->
<!--            <field name="name">Human Resources</field>-->
<!--            <field name="sequence">45</field>-->
<!--        </record>-->
```

And update the base module, this (Human Resources) field is still in this menu !?

Why it is not deleted? Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Model *'ir.module.category'* doesn't have delete access rights (ref https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/odoo/addons/base/security/ir.model.access.csv#L20). So once a record is created from the xml file, it will not delete if you comment that code line.

You can directly delete it from the database using delete query.

Answer (score 1):

Odoo will only show categories that do not have a parent and that one of the subcategories is linked to a module.

If the [category_id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py#L959-L983) field is defined in the search panel, Odoo will use a custom domain:

```
domain = [('parent_id', '=', False), ('child_ids.module_ids', '!=', False)]
```

To show the custom category in the search panel:

First, define the module category as follows:

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="module_custom_category">
    <field name="name">custom_category</field>
    <field name="sequence">99</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.module.category" id="module_child_category">
    <field name="name">child_category</field>
    <field name="parent_id" ref="module_custom_category"/>
</record>
```

Then set it in a module `__manifest__.py` file:

```
'category': 'custom_category/child_category',
```

**Why Odoo did not remove the category after commenting the XML definition?**

Odoo will create two categories with the same name (`custom_category`) with the following XML IDS:

```
base.module_category_custom_category
stack15.module_custom_category
```

And use the first one to show it in the search panel.

When you comment record XML definition and upgrade the module, Odoo will remove the category using the module name as a prefix in its XML id (`stack15.module_custom_category`) and keep the base category (`base.module_category_custom_category`), so the custom category will be visible even if you uninstall the module.